# Hyper-reflexivity constant

Tags: operator-theory

Is there any paper related to the hyper-reflexivity constant of the group von Neumann algebras $vN(\mathbb{F}_n),$ where $\mathbb{F}_n$ is the free group on $n$ geneartors or even better for the communtant $(vN(\mathbb{F}_n))^\prime$ ?

Comment: (How) Is the hyper-reflexivity constant related to the similarity length in the sense of Pisier?

Comment: It is related to the similarity property (weak similarity property).